# how to customize the build of a visual c 2010 project to use different compiler and linker?

Tags: compiler-construction, msbuild

We have a Visual Studio 2010 project that comprises of a bunch of C source files.

These files need to be compiled and then linked using a special tool chain for an embedded device.

Currently, we are compiling it in Visual Studio using the default C++ build and then, in the post build event we are invoking the tool chain for the embedded device.

I am wondering if there is some way to make Visual Studio compile and link using our tool chain instead of Microsoft's.

I tried to override the Build target, and had some progress with that, however when project properties gets changed by a developer, then the project's vcxproj file gets overwritten.

What is the proper way to override the Build target?

Regards,
Adrian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to use custom tool chain with Visual Studio 2010 is to set custom platform toolset:

```
<PlatformToolset>Intel C++ Compiler XE 12.1</PlatformToolset>
```

Here, I am using Intel C++ Compiler. When building the project MSBuild looks for platform toolset in directory:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\$(Architecture)\PlatformToolsets\
```

where `$(Architecture)` is `x64`, `Win32` etc.

But, to use your custom tool chain you will have to write MSBuild configurations files. In my case Intel C++ Compiler comes with such files. So, all I need to do - is to set proper platform toolset (this can be done from Visual Studio 2010 in project properties window).

Here the link to article from Visual C++ Team Blog where you can find more details:
[C++ Native Multi-Targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx)